# Keycloak invalid_redirect_uri

Tags: tomcat

am adding SSO on a sample application within tomcat 7

Added jars to tomcat lib, valve to the application meta-inf/context.xml and sample keycloak-saml.xml within the WEB-INF as per the guide

My client application is a localhost application with url http://localhost:8280/sample/* ..so I registerd same on Valid Redirect URIs.

Now, once i access http://localhost:8280/sample/, it is getting redirect to IDP server ..but it says "Invalid redirect uri"

2015-11-23 16:14:46,866 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-89) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=demo, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_redirect_uri

Any suggestion - how to debug to find out what is missing

Comment: were you able to solve this?